# Python Speech to text model integration with flutter

Tags: python, flutter, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

so I have a complete speech to text and text to speech model in python but I have to integrate it with flutter, is that possible? or should I try to use flutter speech to text/text to speech which will be a waste of time for me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you can run the model online then make API calls from flutter. If you're using Tensorflow then you can export the model as a tensorflow lite model then use this [library](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite) to run the model in Flutter.